# cant use optparse saved parameters because it is <value> type (PYTHON)

Tags: python, regex, type-conversion, optparse

The parameters a user gives to the code is "inputs" variable

```
inputs,args=parser.parse_args()
```

However, when I try to apply a regex in it (I want the user to digit valid parameters for a option), I cant because when I try something like

```
re.match(r"((\w{2}[^\w]){5}\w{2})",inputs["Dictionary_Key"])
```

Python fails because "regex expects a strings or bytes object", but parse_args() returns a <opt.Values> data type
How can I convert ?
I've tried

```
option_dict = vars(inputs)
```

and

```
str(inputs)
```

but neither resolved my problem

Comment: Try instead `re.match(r"((\w{2}[^\w]){5}\w{2})", str(inputs["Dictionary_Key"]))` - You need to be specific about the value you need turned into a `str`.

Comment: What if you pass `str(inputs.Dictionary_Key)`?

Comment: str(inputs["Dictionary_Key"]) says " 'Values' Object is not subscriptable" and str(inputs.Dictionary_Key) says that regex expects a string or bytes object :(

Comment: btw, for some reason when I tried (inputs,args) instead of inputs,args and after that wrote var_to_be_key_value=inputs.Dic_Key then this new variable became a string